# How to use $$hashKey in my app?

Tags: angularjs

How to use $$hashKey in app.
The situation is next:
I make a call to server to receive array of objects, than I pass the array to ng-repeat:

```
 function listWorkItems(data) {
        if (data.ok) {
            vm.workItems = data.content.items;

        }
    }
```

than every second I make a call to server and want to check if received array (data.content.items) differ from listed in DOM (vm.workItems);

to check it I use:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.content.items.length; i++) {
                   if(JSON.stringify(data.content.items[i]) !== JSON.stringify(vm.workItems[i])) {
                       vm.workItems[i] = data.content.items[i];
                   }
 }
```

But I always receuiev NOT equal, because in vm.workItems there is $$hashkey.
what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `angular.toJson` instead of  `JSON.stringify` and try it.

```
(var i=0; i<data.content.items.length; i++) {
   console.log(angular.toJson(data.content.items[i]))
   console.log(angular.toJson(vm.workItems[i]))
   if(angular.toJson(data.content.items[i]) !== angular.toJson(vm.workItems[i])) {
       vm.workItems[i] = data.content.items[i];
   }
```

Using `angular.toJson`, angular removes such sort of extra values.

Comment: just console both the values and check what is coming, check my ans once.